# How many Perakim and Beraytot in the Tosefta?

Tags: statistics, tosefta

I am trying to make a schedule.

How many Perakim and Beraytot in the Tosefta?

Comment: Search for תוספתא חזון יחזקאל on http://www.hebrewbooks.org - count them and report back.

Answer (score 3):

I looked through Table of Contents on each tractate on [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Tanaitic) and arrived at this breakdown by orders:
Zeraim 54
Moed 64
Nashim 66
Nezikin 71
Kodshim 60
Taharot 107

So in total there are 422 chapters of Tosefta.